# Javascript wrap all text nodes in tags

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked but almost all of the answers use the `wrap` function of jQuery.  I'm trying to figure out a plain javascript way of doing this:

```
<div id="content">
    "hey"
    <br>
    <br>
    "foo"
    "bar"
</div>
<script>
    function mainFocusOut(e) {
        //here or any other focus outs...create a function to look between <br> tags and put everything into divs
        if (e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        for (var i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; i++) {
            //I'm not sure if I need a closure function here inside the loop so it works on each individual textNode
            (function(i) {
                var curNode = target.childNodes[i];
                if (curNode.nodeName === "#text") {
                    var element = document.createElement("div");
                    element.appendChild(curNode);
                    target.insertBefore(element, curNode);
                    //NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
                }
            })(i);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Of course the desired output is all the text nodes to be between div tags, same position.  What am I doing wrong?  And is it as simple as what I have here, just a simple loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me, that all you need to do is switch around these two lines:

```
element.appendChild(curNode);
target.insertBefore(element, curNode);
```

so it becomes:

```
target.insertBefore(element, curNode);
element.appendChild(curNode);
```

Because right now, you append the curNode to the new div, before placing the div in the correct position. This results in:

```
<div>"hey"</div>
```

That's all great, but then in order to put the div on the right place, you can not place it before `"hey"` anymore, since you just put that inside the div.

By swapping the two lines, you first place the div in front of the `"hey"`:

```
<div></div>"hey"
```

And *then* you position "hey" correctly inside the div:

```
<div>"hey"</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer...the strange thing occurring is it's inserting a `br` between "foo" and "bar".  Any idea why it would?

Comment: Is it actually creating a new `<br>`, or is it moving one of the existing ones?

Comment: It's just how the `<div id="content">` is formatting the html tags.  Initially, raw html between "foo" and "bar" has a `<br>` tag...and once they get wrapped in `div` tags, it looks like there's a double `<br>`, know what I mean?  You answer is correct

Comment: Changing divs to wrapping with a span actually does exactly what I need!!! Thanks

Comment: Ah, of course, the good old 'new line' that default divs give us. Glad to have helped - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution that depends on the string object methods `split` and `indexOf`

```
<script>
function enclose(id, cutString){
  out = '';
  target = document.getElementById(id);
  text = target.innerHTML;
  if (text.indexOf(cutString) == -1){
    return true;
  }
  parts = text.split(cutString);
  for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
     out += '<div class="new-div">'+parts[i]+'</div>';
  }
  target.innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/vagayo/1/)

### Update

The follwing demo is an update to neglect the empty parts using `match(/\w/gi)` conditional check through the `for` loop. Checkout it [**here**](http://jsbin.com/vagayo/2/).